# use smtp to programmatically send an email

Tags: 7

i am trying to replace the below smtp client with a fake smtp server, in order to use it for dev purposes. I am using the https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp, but whatever i tried failed. In the body of the mail message, i include html also.

How would you suggest i edited below code, in order to be able to send the emails through the drupal smtp mechanism? I have set the smtp server details in the smtp module settings.

```
function send_email($data, $simulate = 0) {

    $kok = '';
    if ($data['p_nid']) {
        $pon = node_load($data['p_nid']);
        $kok = node_load($pon->og_group_ref['und'][0]['target_id']);
        if ($pon->field_wrong_email['und'][0]['value']) return 0;
    }
    if ($data['l_nid']) $kok = node_load($data['l_nid']);


    $gid = $kok->nid ? $kok->nid : $data['gid'];


    //create the senddata array
    $send_data = [
        'sender'    => $data['from'],
        'to'      => $data['to'],
        'subject' => $data['subject'],
        'htmlContent'    => $data['message']
    ];

    //attaching files if exist
    if (is_array($data['attachments'])) $send_data['attachment'] = $data['attachments'];
    if (is_array($data['files'])) {
        foreach ($data['files'] as $file) {
            $name = str_replace('.log','.txt',drupal_basename($file));
            $send_data['attachment'][] = ['content'=>base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)), 'name'=>$name];
        }
    }

    //from
    $str = $kok->title;
    if (mb_substr($str,0,68) != $str) {
        if ($kok->field_email_from['und'][0]['value']) $str = $kok->field_email_from['und'][0]['value'];
        else $str = mb_substr($str,0,68);
    }
    if (!$data['from']) {
        $send_data['sender'] = ['email'=>'someemail', 'name'=>'name'];
        if ($kok->nid) {
            $send_data['sender'] = ['email'=>'someemail', 'name'=>str_replace(',',' ',$str)];
        }
    }

    //reply-to
    if (($kok->nid) and ($kok->field_email['und'][0]['email'])) {
        $send_data['replyTo'] = ['email'=>$kok->field_email['und'][0]['email'], 'name'=> str_replace(',',' ',$str)];
    }
    $config = SendinBlue\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', 'APIKEYHERE');
    $apiInstance = new SendinBlue\Client\Api\SMTPApi(
        new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
        $config
    );

    $sendSmtpEmail = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmail($send_data);

    if (!$simulate) {
        try {
            $result = $apiInstance->sendTransacEmail($sendSmtpEmail);
            $msg_id = $result->getMessageId();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception when calling SMTPApi->sendTransacEmail: ', $e->getCode().' '.$e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
            $err_msg = $e->getCode().' '.$e->getMessage(). '   l_nid='.$kok->nid.' '.$kok->title.' p_nid='.$data['p_nid'].' email_to='.$data['to']['email'].' '.var_dump($send_data);
            watchdog('sendinblue',$err_msg,[],WATCHDOG_ALERT);
            $msg = $e->getMessage();
            $pos = strpos($msg,'response:');
            $json = substr($msg, $pos+9, 1000);
            $json = json_decode($json);
            if (is_object($json) and ($json->message == "email is not valid in to")) {
                $pon = node_load($data['p_nid']);
                $pon->field_wrong_email['und'][0]['value'] = 1;
                node_save($pon);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could make this a lot easier and require no code by using Mailhog in your local development stack.

Comment: could you please elaborate? I can use mailhog, still though, i am trying with code to send the email, using the smtp drupal module. Now i use an api, as you have seen in the code

Comment: Mailhog catches all outgoing mail so its never actually sent to anyone - I guess I am not following why you are writing the code above if its for testing?

Comment: the above code is used for production. My question is how i should alter the sendinblue part of the above code, so as to be able to use the smtp drupal 7 module, and mailhog